# SII-IGIC (ATC) WS in .NET - SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas/SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasRequest

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, asp.net-web-api, aeat-sii

antes que nada perdonen mi español pero estoy desesperada y creo que aquí me pueden ayudar.

¿Alguien ha creado un Webservice en .NET para comunicarse con el SII-IGIC de Canarias?

No estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo, ¿alguien puede compartir un ejemplo?

Comparto mi código por si alguien tiene la amabilidad de ayudarme:

Service:

```js
private readonly siiSOAP _siiSoapClient;
public IgicService()
{
    _siiSoapClient = CreateConfiguredSiiSoapClient();
}
private siiSOAPClient CreateConfiguredSiiSoapClient()
{
    var client = new siiSOAPClient(siiSOAPClient.EndpointConfiguration.SuministroFactEmitidas);
    ConfigureClientCertificate(client); //get the certificate
    return client;
}
```

Function called in the controller:

```
public async Task ProcessJsonAndSendToIgic(string jsonPayload)
{
    var requestObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonIGIC>(jsonPayload);

    var siiRequest = ConvertToSiiRequest(requestObject); //returns SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasRequest type 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TESTE");
    try
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasRequest));

        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE");
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE BEFORE SZED");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, siiRequest);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE SZED");
                var serializedXml = textWriter.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Serialized XML:");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializedXml);

                 StoreRequestInDatabaseSTR(serializedXml, requestObject.InvoicerID);
                }
                else if (requestObject.Invoicer.Equals("ONL"))
                {
                    StoreRequestInDatabaseONL(serializedXml, requestObject.InvoicerID);
                }*/
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OUT");
        var response = await _siiSoapClient.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasAsync(siiRequest); //last step, gives me SOAP Fault: certificado cliente obligatorio, am i missing something? Shouldn't i add request/response code? like URL definition, method definition, http headers definition etc?
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Response");
        if (response.RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas != null)
        {
            var responseXml = SerializeResponseToXml(response.RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseXml); // Log to console

           
            //await StoreResponseInDatabase(responseXml);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No response received from SII IGIC web service.");
        }
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException faultException)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SOAP Fault: {faultException.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"General Error: {ex.Message}");
    }

}
```

en la linea

> var response = await _siiSoapClient.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasAsync(siiRequest);

dame SOAP Fault: certificado cliente obligatorio, pero imprimí los datos del certificado y me lo devolví sin ningún problema